# NHibernate: Initializing an unitialized collection from a detached entity, not possible?

Tags: nhibernate, lazy-loading

Example:

```
public class ParentObj
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<ChildObj> ChildCollection { get; set; } //Lazy loaded
}
```

Some method that get the parent obj on one page (web)

```
ParentObj parentObj;
using (var session = GetSesion())
using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    parentObj = session.Get<ParentObj>(1);
    //Don't want to call NHibernateUtil.Initialize() here 
    //because ChildCollection is not needed for the current operation
}
```

Transfer parentObj to another page, now I need to access the ChildCollection

```
var parentOjb = GetParentOjbFromPreviousPage();
using (var session = GetSesion())
using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    parentOjb = session.Merge(parentObj);
    NHibernateUtil.Initialize(parentObj.ChildCollection); //exception thrown here
}
```

Error message: collection is not associated with any session

What am I doing wrong? Is the only way to initialize the ChildCollection in this scenario is to call Get() again?

Comment: Are you sure the error is happening on the Merge call? or the line underneath?

Comment: I apologize, you are correct, the error message is thrown when calling Initialize(). I've updated the original post.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Glad you realised the problem was elsewhere, according to the [Hibernate docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-saveorupdate)

> - if there is a persistent instance with the same identifier currently associated with the session, copy the state of the given
>     object onto the persistent instance
> - if there is no persistent instance currently associated with the session, try to load it from the database, or create a new persistent
>     instance
> - the persistent instance is returned
> - the given instance does not become associated with the session, it remains detached

I have never tried this but what happens if you do:-

```
using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    var dbObj = session.Merge(parentObj);
    //do something with dbObj.Childcollection
}
```

It looks like that a `select` is called and it is this object that is used to merge your dettached object into. Therefore it is this object you need to use afterwards for lazy loading etc (proxing)

Comment: i had the same logic so the codes i posted should've worked, the problem was elsewhere in my code, thanks to your comment though i looked over some codes and found the problem. sometime it just takes someone else to kind of turn on the light bulb in your head. thanks!

Comment: No worries. Glad I ultimately helped.

Answer (score 0):

I just had same problem.I changed merge to SaveorUpdate.

So, your code will be:

```
using (var session = GetSesion())
using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    parentOjb = session.SaveorUpdate(parentObj);
    NHibernateUtil.Initialize(parentObj.ChildCollection); 
}
```